# A different notion of convergence for this sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was thinking about sequences, and my mind came to one defined like this:

-1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...

Where the first term is -1, and after the nth occurrence of -1 in the sequence, the next n terms of the sequence are 1, followed by -1, and so on. Which led me to perhaps a stronger example,

-1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, ...

Where the first term is -1, and after the nth occurrence of -1 in the sequence, the next $2^n$ terms of the sequence are 1, followed by -1, and so on.

By the definition of convergence or by Cauchy's criterion, the sequence does not converge, as any N one may choose to define will have an occurrence of -1 after it, which must occur within the next N terms (and certainly this bound could be decreased)

However, due to the decreasing frequency of -1 in the sequence, I would be tempted to say that there is some intuitive way in which this sequence converges to 1. Is there a different notion of convergence that captures the way in which this sequence behaves?

Comment: +1 interesting idea, hope people with more experience in analysis can provide more insight

Comment: The [Cesaro Mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean) may do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most methods of [summing divergent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series) can be adapted to making divergent sequences converge.  For instance, Cesaro summation replaces the $n^\text{th}$ term of a series with the mean of the first $n$ terms.  You could do the same: replace the $n^\text{th}$ term of your sequence with the mean of the first $n$ terms.  Then you would be able to show convergence to $1$ (after this replacement) in the normal sense.

[Abel summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem) would be adapted to replace the $N^\text{th}$ term in your series with $\lim_{z \rightarrow 1^-} \sum_{n=0}^N a_n z^n$.

And so on for other methods.

Hardy's book, *Divergent Series* is a fun read with a lot of interesting stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The [Cesaro mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean) accomplishes something that is close to your intuition.

For the sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots$, the Cesaro mean is the limit, if it exists, of the sequence $(b_n)$, where $b_n=\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}{n}$.

If the limit of $(a_n)$ is $a$, then the Cesaro mean of the sequence $(a_n)$ is $a$. But the Cesaro mean of the sequence $(a_n)$ may exist when the limit does not. The Cesaro mean of the sequence in your post is $1$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

As  André Nicolas wrote,
the Cesaro mean,
for which the $n$-th term
 is the average of the
first $n$ terms
will do what you want.

In both your cases,
for large $n$,
if $(a_n)$ is your sequence,
if
$b_n = \frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k
$,
then
$b_n \to 1$
since the number of $-1$'s
gets arbitrarily small
compared to the number of $1$'s.